# Keras-logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 1) vs (None, 363))

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, nlp

I have been using "CMU Movie Summary Corpus" for movie genre classification for my own learning since I am relatively new to NLP. This is a multi-label classification task. I am using TF-IDF for word vectorization and then feeding the output into Neural Network but I get the following error when I try to train my model:

```
ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 1) vs (None, 363))
```

I have read on StackOverflow and tried to implement the same but the issue persists. However, I am able to train machine learning models using the same TF-IDF features but unable to train the neural network.

Below is the code snippet:

**create TF-IDF features**

```
xtrain_tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(xtrain)
xval_tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(xval)

xtrain_tfidf[0]

//xtrain_tfidf[0] <1x10000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'with 63 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

**Building Neural Network**

```
xtrain_tfidf = xtrain_tfidf.toarray()
xval_tfidf = xval_tfidf.toarray()
```

**Preprocess the data by setting all arrays to the same size using padding**

```
train_data = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(xtrain_tfidf,
                                                        value=0,
                                                        padding='post',
                                                        maxlen=2000)

test_data = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(xval_tfidf,
                                                       value=0,
                                                       padding='post',
                                                       maxlen=2000)
```

**input shape is the vocabulary count used for the movie reviews (10,000 words)**

```
vocab_size = 10000

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(20, kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001),
                       activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(2000,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(16, kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001),
                       activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
])
```

**Model features**

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

**Create a cross-validation set**

```
x_val = train_data[:1000]
partial_x_train = train_data[1000:]

y_val = y_train[:1000]
partial_y_train = y_train[1000:]
```

**Train the model for 40 epochs**

```
history = model.fit(partial_x_train,
                    partial_y_train,
                    epochs=40,
                    batch_size=512,
                    validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
                    verbose=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a multi-class classification task thus this

```
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
```

should have as many outputs as there are classes (363?) and you should use softmax, not sigmoid (unless a single point can belong to multiple classes?)

```
    keras.layers.Dense(363, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
```

Also your loss should not be `binary_crossentropy` but `categorical_crossentropy`  for the same reason.

Comment: OP says that's multi-label classification.

Comment: @lejlot Yes, I did the same configurations in my Neural Network but didn't work.